# Matlab Quadprog Constraint

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to use quadprog in matlab.
The variable is a matrix X.
My problem has a linear constraint saying diag(AX)<= b, where A is a matrix and b is a vector.
However, since quadprog only accepts vector variables, the inequality constraint above should be reformulated in vector form. But I do not know how.
Can you help me to do so?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that A and X are square matrices, of size nxn.

What are the diagonal elements? Temporarily, I'll call

```
C = diag(A*X)
```

What is C(i,i) ?

```
C(i,i) = sum(A(i,j)*X(j,i))
```

where the sum is over j. Essentially the i'th diagonal element of C is a dot product between the i'th row of A and the i'th column of X. There are n such dot products, which are trivially written in matrix form.

Of course, if A and X are not square, the same holds as long as they conform for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think I did not get your point. Does your answer give me a way of writing the constraint in A*X<=b form, where X is a *vector*? (Because that is what quadprog interface requires.)

Comment: Yes, it DOES, but I won't do your work for you. Even though X is a matrix as you pass it in, the matrix inequality constraints will assume that X is a vector of length n^2. You will need to build the appropriate matrix inequality constraint that essentially extracts the proper elements of X.

Comment: What you need to understand is that quadprog minimizes a SCALAR objective, defined as 0.5*x'*H*x+f'*x. So even if X is an array as you pass it in, the objective is formulated with X unrolled into a vector. This is also true for the inequality constraints.

Comment: Okay now I am starting to understand your hints. Thank you.